# Changes textbox text value from the array after selecting item from listview

Tags: c#, arrays, listview

Hello guys I just want to find an answer to my question

Here is it.

I have an array named price

```
int [] price = new int[5] {2311,3122, 4203, 4075, 5525};
```

Here's the listview code

```
for(int i = 0; i<price.length; i++)
{
textbox2.text = price[i].toString();
}
```

it doesn't work

how can I make it work like if selected index change array index also change and textbox text value will also change based on the selected index.

Comment: You don't need a loop for that, textbox2.text = price[selectedIndex].toString(); should do.

Comment: better to use list selection changed event or set textbox is empty in for loop before setting the text box value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to catch the **ItemSelectionChangedEvent** of the **ListView**, and assign the textbox value based on the current index

```
private void ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(Object sender, ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e) {    
        textbox2.Text = price[e.ItemIndex].ToString();    
    }
```